# Xamarin.Forms/iOS, got exception, "You_Should_Not_Call_Base_In_This_Method"?

Tags: c#, android, ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I have a Xamarin.Forms project and has implemented a third-party service, the Android part is almost perfect, but the iOS deployment is continually throwing the exception. I totally have no idea about this exception because in the code I got all the return value right in the method invoking. So, I wonder what is the "Base" and which place should I check?

Here is the exception:

[image]

And here's the part of the code where throw the exception:

```
void Join_Clicked(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    String channelName = this.Room_Name_Entry.Text;
    if (channelName != null)
    {
        if (myEngine.AgoraJoinChannel(channelName) == 0)
        {
            this.VoiceStatus.Text = "You are in the channel!";
            this.VoiceStatus.IsVisible = true;
            this.Room_Join_Button.IsEnabled = false;
        }
        else
        {
            this.VoiceStatus.Text = "You are not in the channel!";
            this.VoiceStatus.IsVisible = true;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        this.VoiceStatus.Text = "Please set the room's name!";
        this.VoiceStatus.IsVisible = true;
    }
}
```

Here's the platform-specific implement:

```
using System;
using DT.Xamarin.Agora;
using TabbedPageTest.iOS;

[assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Dependency(typeof(AgoraVoiceImplement_iOS))]
namespace TabbedPageTest.iOS
{
    public class AgoraVoiceImplement_iOS : IAgora
    {
        AgoraRtcEngineKit myEngine;
        AgoraRtcEngineDelegate myDelegate;

        public AgoraVoiceImplement_iOS()
        {
            myDelegate = new AgoraRtcEngineDelegate();
            myEngine = AgoraRtcEngineKit.SharedEngineWithAppIdAndDelegate("6de68f576fda42ca92a791b38383fee8", myDelegate);
        }

        public int AgoraJoinChannel(string Channel_Name)
        {
            myEngine.SetChannelProfile(AgoraRtcChannelProfile.Communication);
            return myEngine.JoinChannelByKey(null, Channel_Name, "", 0, (Foundation.NSString arg1, nuint arg2, nint arg3) =>
            {
                myDelegate.DidJoinChannel(myEngine, arg1, arg2, arg3);
            });
        }

        public int AgoraLeaveChannel()
        {
            return myEngine.LeaveChannel((AgoraRtcStats obj) =>
            {
                myDelegate.DidLeaveChannelWithStats(myEngine, obj);
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Many thanks!

Comment: Break on the exception. Look in the call stack. See where base gets called. Probably in one of your delegates.

Answer (score 1):

You have a delegate somewhere in your code that implements interface/class for that delegate base and it calls the base class implementation.

Xamarin SDK has the concept for base classes for delegates (because of the C# nature), but that is not how it is on actual IOS SDK ObjC with protocols. So Xamarin added this exception to mark it when executed to find the place where either leave the implementation empty or add your custom code to handle the callback on the delegate.

Search in the code for that or add Break On Exception in debugger and it will stop once this is invoked.